# Using Java to parse json and print key and vaules

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonparser

I have the following json and need some help reading the json and key value pairs. Using Java how can I read this out?

I'm trying to use 'org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser' and just cannot read out the key and values.

Here is my attempt to read the items:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(ds.getDoceboCourseData());
        
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        
        JSONArray items = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");
        
        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = items.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

JSON:

```
{
   "data":{
      "items":[
         {
            "user_id":"111",
            "username":"111",
            "email":"blah@blah.com",
            "first_name":"blah",
            "last_name":"blah",
            "level":"Learner",
            "enrollment_date":"2020-06-26 00:43:49",
            "active_from":null,
            "active_until":null,
            "status":"Completed",
            "status_id":"2",
            "level_id":"3",
            "user_status_id":"1",
            "user_status":"Active",
            "score_given":"0.00",
            "forced_score_given":false,
            "date_complete":"2020-06-26 01:04:01"
         }
      ],
      "count":10,
      "has_more_data":true,
      "current_page":1,
      "current_page_size":10,
      "total_page_count":3,
      "total_count":23
   },
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "_links":[

   ]
}
```

Comment: You have an outer-object. So the first key is 'data': 'data'->'items'. Why aren't you using a more advanced JSON (de)serialization library, like Jackson or GSON?

Comment: Please clarify "cannot read out the key and values". Are you not seeing *any* results, or you are seeing something unexpected like exception stacktrace or compilation error?

Comment: Sorry ... getting null value error here:  JSONArray items = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("items");

Comment: You mean NullPointerException is being thrown?

Comment: yes... cannot seem to find the items

Comment: In JSON `{}` represents an object and `[]` represents an array. When you parse something like `{foo: {bar: "abc"} }` then you are getting object with key `foo`. That `foo` key has its own object with key `bar` and value `"abc"`. So when you want to bet to `"abc"` start by getting value under `foo` key and then from that returned object read value of `bar` key. Currently what you are doing is asking for `bar`, but most outer object doesn't have that key so it returns `null`.

Comment: You can also consider looking at your JSON as a directory tree. Using hat analogy your code would be like attempting to read `/items` instead of `/data/items`. In other words first `get("data")` then on result `get("items")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Pshemo :

```
public void parsedJSON(String json) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("data");

    System.out.printf("Object : " + obj);

    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        String status = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("status");
        String empId = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("username");
        System.out.printf("Id : %s  Status : %s %n",  empId, status);
    }
```